# Decimal value assertion in q-unit

Tags: jquery, qunit

How do I assert correct decimal value with a bit of tolerance?

Lets say I want to assert this:  `1 / 3`

I don't want to assert this with a long string like this: `equal(1 / 3, 0.3333333333333333)`
I would like to specify tolerance for it like this: `equal(1 / 3, 0.33, 0.01)` // As in... value can be from 0.32 to 0.34

Is this possible in q-unit? One possible solution to this would be if i multiplied the result by like 1000 and cut away all the decimal places... But i will be writing many such tests and would prefer to use any already implemented feature of q-unit is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is close-enough addon for qunit. It extends qunit with 2 assertion methods which do exactly what you need:
https://github.com/jquery/qunit/tree/master/addons/close-enough

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in function for this, but you could make your own:

```
function decEqual(actual expected, tolerance, message) {
      ok(Math.abs(actual - expected) <= tolerance, message);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
decEqual(1 / 3, 0.33, 0.01, 'Invalid third');
```